# updating shadow file in a KVM guest in a mounted system

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, mount, password-reset, shadow

I have a KVM guest that I need to reset the password. If I use 'virsh console' to access the guest account, I'm able to update the shadow file with a new hash line like '$6$avdwsefs$In0A44PGN3xHczlF4qeF5wrVs6WmeCfTUYB1WZ1g6Co.fq62l5/0ZbrnGWbjhRQT598eAKDo/nMaW6iJCA3k2.'. If I reboot the guest account, the new password works. But if I mount the guest system in server and update the shadow file in /mnt directory, the password won't work. Both the old password hash and new password hash won't work after I modify shadow file in the mounted directory.

Update: Both the server system and vps guest system have centos6.4 and the latest update of glibc.

Answer (score 2):

The password hashes are encrypted with `crypt(3)`.

Make sure that the glibc is supporting SHA-512 encryption. E.g. you have glibc 2.7 or newer. Otherwise those hashes will be ignored by crypt.

From the `crypt(e)` man page:

> The glibc2 version of this function supports additional encryption algorithms.
>   If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$" followed by a string terminated by "$":
>   $id$salt$encrypted

...

> ID  | Method
>   1   | MD5
>   2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some Linux distributions)
>   5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>   6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)